# Change php generate css field enclosure and field separator

Tags: php, csv

We use the following script, but that generates a csv file with field separator `,` and field enclosure `"`. But I want to change that to the following:

field enclosure: `'`

field separator: `;`

How can we change that?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '12288M');

require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$file_path = "var/import/productname.csv";
$mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$products_row = $_parseObjects = $_additional = [];
$_product = null;
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_config = Mage::getModel('seo/config');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(2000)->setCurPage(1);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    global $_product;
    $_product = $product;
    $seo = getCurrentSeo();

    $productnamestring = $seo->getTitle();

    $findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/');
    $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');
    $productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);

    $data = array();
    $data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
    $data['name'] = $productnamingseo;
    $products_row[] = $data;
}

$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $products_row);
echo 'Done!';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
$mage_csv->setDelimiter(';');
$mage_csv->setEnclosure("'");
$mage_csv->saveData($file_path, $products_row);
```

Comment: Never knew it was that easy. Thanks a lot! :)